# "Provided add-in package was not understood...." - Error in Teams developer portal - Manifest version 1.16

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

We tried creating a personal app in Teams developer portal (https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps), and its giving an error in the **Publish to store** page.

**Error: Provided add-in package was not understood. Please, make sure that the file being submitted is a valid Office add-in package.**

[Screenshot of the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpkS0.png)

This error is shown even when I create a new app, without entering any configurations also. I was not able to import the sample app given by developer portal as well.

We were able to create apps with no errors until we had the 1.15 manifest version.

This is a blocker for us to go ahead with a Teams store submission.

Sample manifest file which showed up errors:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifestVersion": "1.16",
  "id": "57a782c0-8316-4922-a1da-e20c7a1f92b0",
  "packageName": "com.package.name",
  "name": {
    "short": "Test",
    "full": "Booking portal"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "ibi",
    "mpnId": "",
    "websiteUrl": "https://example.com/",
    "privacyUrl": "https://example.com/",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://example.com/"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "test description",
    "full": "long long text"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "outline.png",
    "color": "color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "2fc3eb14-4f86-474b-974e-1d9edaa2c47e",
      "name": "home",
      "contentUrl": "https://example.com/",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ],
      "context": [
        "personalTab"
      ]
    },
    {
      "entityId": "about",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "example.com"
  ]
}
```

Would request the corresponding people related to this issue, to respond to this post, please.

We tried creating an app package in developer portal of Microsoft teams (https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/home).
And we expected to not show any errors in publish to store page.

Answer (score 1):

"entityId" for your tab is not meant specifically to be a guid, it's just meant to be a unique string, for instance to support Deep Linking - see more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-application?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-a-deep-link-to-your-tab

However, I don't think that's your problem, it's more likely the "about" entry - it's not valid. Do you have an actual "about" page you want to include? If so, you need to complete the remaining "required" values like you've done for the other tab. If not, remove that "about" entry.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Hilton
No, we haven't added any "about" tab, its added by the developer portal itself and we don't have any option to edit/remove the "about" tab.
Is there any way we can remove the 'About' tab which is getting added automatically?

Comment: But, in the previous version of manifest, 1.15, the About entity id was the same. And we did not get any errors then.

Comment: I don't know why it got added, but try take it out and see if it makes a difference. Export the manifest, then delete the app in the dev portal, edit the file (e.g. in Visual Studio Code) and then re-upload it.

Comment: Thank you for the response Hilton. Tried doing that, it wasn't allowing to import that app package. Will try again.

Comment: ok. sorry it didn't help. You can also consider rolling back to an earlier manifest version, if you don't need 1.15 or 1.16 specifically

Comment: I don't see an option to roll back to previous version as well.

Comment: Manifest version 1.15 was perfectly working fine. But can't see any option to roll back :(

Comment: The issue is fixed! I think Microsoft has updated the version internally. Its still 1.16. But my issue is resolved.